# TypeError: Cannot set property 'auto' of null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I get `TypeError: Cannot set property 'auto' of null when i try to update my mongodb using angularjs on the frnt end and nodejs on the backend. Here is my code :

my angular code:

```
scope.lol.then(function(user){
  console.log(user[0]._id);
  iden=user[0]._id;
  $scope.userss = user;
  console.log(iden);

  $http.put('/api/updateUser', user[0]);
});
```

And my api :

```
module.exports.updateUser = function (req, res) {
  var id = req.param.id;
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    if (err) throw err;

    // change the users location
    user.auto = 'true';

    // save the user
    user.save(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;

      console.log('User successfully updated!');
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: The error means that in the statement `user.auto = 'true';` the variable `user` contains `null`.

Comment: Apparently, `User.findById` doesn't find a `User` for the passed `id`.

Comment: Rather than `req.param.id` try `JSON.parse(req.body).id`

Comment: @dan thank you now am getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 and of course a 500

Comment: If you console.log(req.body) what does it look like?

Comment: Also, don't forget that **not finding** a user **won't** raise any error. You'll have to check the existence of the user, with `if (!user) { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$http.put('/api/updateUser', user[0]);
```

change to

```
$http.put('/api/updateUser', {params:{id:user[0]._id}});
```

and on api

```
var id = req.param.id;
```

change to

```
var id = req.query.id;
```

Comment: He wants a PUT request with a body - your answer is just tacking it on as a query parameter. Next time he wants to read a body of a request in an endpoint, he will run into the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you're using ExpressJS for your API, so you'll need to use `body-parser` to retrieve the body of your request. You can read more about it here: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html - ctrl+f for body-parser to skip to the good bits :)

Try something like this in your API (you'll probably need to tweak it to fit your app, but it shows you how to pull stuff out of the body of the request. There are code examples on the link I posted too):

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ 
  extended: false 
}));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());

app.listen(1337);

app.put('/updateUser', updateUser);

function updateUser (req, res) {
  var id = req.body.id;
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    if (err) throw err;

    // change the users location
    user.auto = 'true';

    // save the user
    user.save(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;

      console.log('User successfully updated!');
    });
  });
}
```

Hope that helps!